# If the state is VH+HV how one can prove experimentally that two photons are identical?

Tags: photons, quantum-optics, polarization, identical-particles

From a SPDC source we get two photons in a $|VH\rangle+|HV\rangle$ state. How is to be proven experimentally that they are identical while one would be in $|H\rangle$ and the other in $|V\rangle$ polarization after a PBS?

Comment: for others as ignorant of the acronym as I was https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spontaneous_parametric_down-conversion

Comment: PBS is polarization beam splitter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you split the photons with a [PBS](https://www.rp-photonics.com/beam_splitters.html#:~:text=somewhat%20different%20amplitudes.-,polarizing%20beam%20splitter%20cubes,-Instead%20of%20glass), you can rotate the polarization of the photon in one arm (say the one with the $|H\rangle$ photon) by $90°$, for example using a [half-wave plate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Waveplate#Half-wave_plate). The state is now $|VV\rangle$.
Then, you combine the now identical photons on a non-polarizing beamsplitter. As of the [Hong-Ou-Mandel effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hong%E2%80%93Ou%E2%80%93Mandel_effect), the photons will leave the beamsplitter in the same direction, if they are identical in all degrees of freedom (polarization, spectrum, timing, transversal position and momentum distribution).

If you place a [single-photon detector](https://www.rp-photonics.com/photon_counting.html) in each exit arm of the beamsplitter, only one of them detects a pair of photons, but they don't simultaneously detect a photon each. However, if the photons are partially distinguishable by the properties listed before, not all of them exit the beamsplitter in the same direction. Therefore, the level of suppression of coincidences is often used to quantify the indistinguishability.

Comment: "Then, you combine the now identical photons on a non-polarizing beamsplitter" .....don't you mean beam combiner?

Comment: @PhysicsDave One can use them in both ways.

Comment: All good. But after PBS the photon should be in superposition of say left channel V and right channel H. Would the case be settled if one puts a stopper in V and a HWP in H?

Comment: @Mercury After the PBS the two photons are sorted according to their polarization and there should be 1 in each arm. What would you settle by blocking the $|V\rangle$ photon?

Comment: I think it is in both arms at once. With both polarizations still present. Just after a detection the WF collapses to H. According to Bohr.

Comment: Maybe I understood incorrectly what you mean with the state $|VH\rangle + |HV\rangle$. To me, that describes _two_ photons, of which one is $H$ and the other $V$ polarized. The superposition describes that either the first is $V$ or the second. But in your last comment you write about _one_ photon being in both arms. Could you clarifiy, what this initial state describes, @Mercury?